How to add data to saved model?
I am testing the phpml package. I am new to neural networks and artificial intelligence. I want to build a comment classifier. In phpml I can save the model and restore it. But now I have new comments. How can I add new data to the model? So as not to retrain the model on the entire amount of data.

To add new data to your model without retraining it entirely, you can utilize incremental learning (or online learning). However, the php-ml library does not directly support incremental learning for all its algorithms, including most neural networks. Here's a breakdown of what you can do:

Check if the Classifier Supports Incremental Learning
Some machine learning algorithms inherently support incremental learning. For example:


Naive Bayes
K-Nearest Neighbors (KNN)
Online SVMs

If you use a classifier like Neural Network (MLP) or Decision Trees in php-ml, they do not support incremental updates to the model. For such algorithms, retraining is generally required when adding new data.

Save the New Comments Separately
You can keep the new comments in a separate dataset. When retraining the model later, you can merge this dataset with the previous one to avoid retraining from scratch.

Full Retraining
If incremental learning isn’t an option for your chosen classifier, you need to retrain the model:


Load the previously saved dataset.
Append the new comments to it.
Retrain the model and save it again.
Here’s an example workflow in php-ml:
use Phpml\ModelManager;
use Phpml\Classification\MLPClassifier;
use Phpml\Model\Persistable;

$modelManager = new ModelManager();

// Load the existing model
/** @var MLPClassifier $classifier */
$classifier = $modelManager->restoreFromFile('comment_classifier.model');

// New data
$newSamples = [
    ['New comment 1 text'], 
    ['New comment 2 text']
];
$newLabels = ['positive', 'negative'];

// Full retraining (retraining combines old and new data)
// Load old data (from your storage or logs)
$oldSamples = [['Old comment 1 text'], ['Old comment 2 text']];
$oldLabels = ['positive', 'neutral'];

$allSamples = array_merge($oldSamples, $newSamples);
$allLabels = array_merge($oldLabels, $newLabels);

$classifier = new MLPClassifier(count($allSamples[0]), [5], ['positive', 'neutral', 'negative']);
$classifier->train($allSamples, $allLabels);

// Save the updated model
$modelManager->saveToFile($classifier, 'comment_classifier.model');


I use Naive Bayes. If the model training has to be restarted all the time, how to load a large amount of data? There may be errors due to insufficient memory.
